# Type on a website's input field and take results in python

Tags: python

I want to write a script that enters an input to an empty input field of a website (like the ones we have here when asking or answering), then tell the website to perform the action that the input is supposed to do and return the results.

In a few words: only with python code, go on google.com, enter something in the search field, perform the search and read results. All these from python.

Is it feasible?

Where can I find some information about this possibility on python?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This question is really hard to understand.  If you are asking "Can python retrieve the value of an HTML form element in the browser?" The answer is NO, python runs on a server and not in a web browser.  If you are asking "Can the web browser connect to the server and tell python do something?", the answer is YES and you should look into [Django.](https://www.djangoproject.com/)